# What is the correct way of using C++ objects (and volatile) inside interrupt routines?

Tags: c++, interrupt, volatile, isr

I am currently working with Atmel AVR microcontrollers (gcc), but would like the answer to apply to the microcontroller world in general, i.e. usually single-threaded but with interrupts.

I know how to use `volatile` in C code when accessing a variable that can be modified in an ISR. For example:

```
uint8_t g_pushIndex = 0;
volatile uint8_t g_popIndex = 0;
uint8_t g_values[QUEUE_SIZE];

void waitForEmptyQueue()
{
    bool isQueueEmpty = false;
    while (!isQueueEmpty)
    {
        // Disable interrupts to ensure atomic access.
        cli();
        isQueueEmpty = (g_pushIndex == g_popIndex);
        sei();
    }
}

ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) // some interrupt routine
{
    // Interrupts are disabled here.
    if (g_pushIndex == g_popIndex)
    {
        usart::stopTransfer();
    }
    else
    {
        uint8_t value = g_values[g_popIndex++];
        g_popIndex &= MASK;
        usart::transmit(value);
    }
}
```

Because g_popIndex is modified inside the ISR and accessed outside of the ISR, it must be declared `volatile` to instruct the compiler not to optimize memory accesses to that variable. Note that, unless I'm mistaken, `g_pushIndex` and `g_values` need not be declared `volatile`, since they are not modified by the ISR.

I want to encapsulate the code related to the queue inside a class, so that it can be reused:

```
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue()
    : m_pushIndex(0)
    , m_popIndex(0)
    {

    }

    inline bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return (m_pushIndex == m_popIndex);
    }

    inline uint8_t pop()
    {
        uint8_t value = m_values[m_popIndex++];
        m_popIndex &= MASK;
        return value;
    }

    // other useful functions here...

private:
    uint8_t m_pushIndex;
    uint8_t m_popIndex;
    uint8_t m_values[QUEUE_SIZE];
};

Queue g_queue;

void waitForEmptyQueue()
{
    bool isQueueEmpty = false;
    while (!isQueueEmpty)
    {
        // Disable interrupts to ensure atomic access.
        cli();
        isQueueEmpty = g_queue.isEmpty();
        sei();
    }
}

ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) // some interrupt routine
{
    // Interrupts are disabled here.
    if (g_queue.isEmpty())
    {
        usart::stopTransfer();
    }
    else
    {
        usart::transmit(g_queue.pop());
    }
}
```

The code above is arguably more readable. However, what should be done about `volatile` in this case?

1) Is it still needed? Does calling the method `Queue::isEmpty()` somehow ensures non-optimized access to `g_queue.m_popIndex`, even if the function is declared `inline`? I doubt that. I know that compilers use heuristics to determine if an access should not be optimized, but I dislike relying on such heuristics as a general solution.

2) I think a working (and efficient) solution is to declare the member `Queue::m_popIndex` `volatile` inside the class definition. However, I dislike this solution, because the designer of class `Queue` needs to know exactly how it will be used to know which member variable must be `volatile`. It will not scale well with future code changes. Also, all `Queue` instances will now have a `volatile` member, even if some are not used inside an ISR.

3) If one looks at the `Queue` class as if it were a built-in, I think the natural solution would be to declare the global instance `g_queue` itself as `volatile`, since it is modified in the ISR and accessed outside of the ISR. However, this doesn't work well, because only `volatile` functions can be called on `volatile` objects. Suddenly, all member functions of `Queue` must be declared `volatile` (not just the `const` ones or the ones used inside the ISR). Again, how can the designer of `Queue` know that in advance? Also, this penalize all `Queue` users. There is still the possibility of duplicating all member functions and having both `volatile` and non-`volatile` overloads in the class, so that non-`volatile` users are not penalized. Not pretty.

4) The `Queue` class could be templated on a policy class that can optionally add `volatile` to all its member variables only when needed. Again, the class designer need to know that in advance and the solution is more complicated to understand, but oh well.

I am curious to know if I am missing some easier solution to this. As a side note, I am compiling with no C++11/14 support (yet).

Comment: Are `cli` and `sei` memory barriers on your platform?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They aren't (I think -- not 100% clear). I have access to a _MemoryBarrier() "instruction" though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I looked more closely to the doc and they are indeed memory barriers.

Comment: I think all of the variables `g_pushIndex`, `g_popIndex` and `g_values` have to be volatile, because all of them are accessed from two contexts (ISR and main). An access is either read or write. I assume  `g_pushIndex` and `g_values` are modified from main.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inline is definetely needed.
1) Compilers generally places a new copy of the inlined function in each place it is called. This optimization seems to not affect volatile variables. So this is OK.
2) I second this as the correct solution(with an extension). Because your only variable that needs to be volatile is really queue index.
3) Nope, no need to mark whole class instance volatile since it may prevent other potential optimizations.
4) You can use inheritance. An interface that declares which functions must a queue have, and two inherited classes for one using with ISR(has queue index volatile) and the other for not using ISR. Additionally, you can always define your class also templated:

```
template<typename T>
class IQueue
{
public:
        virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
        virtual T pop() = 0;
protected:
    uint8_t pushIndex;
    T values[QUEUE_SIZE];
};


template<typename T>
class ISRQueue : public IQueue<T>
{
    volatile uint8_t popIndex;
public:
    inline bool isEmpty()const
    {
        return (pushIndex == popIndex);
    }

    inline T pop()
    {
        T value = values[popIndex++];
        popIndex &= MASK;
        return value;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Queue : public IQueue<T>
{
    uint8_t popIndex;
public:
    inline bool isEmpty()const
    {
        return (pushIndex == popIndex);
    }

    inline T pop()
    {
        T value = values[popIndex++];
        popIndex &= MASK;
        return value;
    }
};

typedef ISRQueue<uint8_t> ISRQueueUInt;
typedef ISRQueue<uint8_t> QueueUInt;
```